# How can I run the iOS 7.1 Simulator in Xcode 7.0 beta 2?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7.1, xcode7-beta2

I have installed latest Xcode 7 beta 2 version, when I am trying to run the application in iOS 7.1 Simulator its giving this error message:

> The iOS 7.1 simulator runtime is not available.
>
> Unable to open liblaunch_sim.dylib.  Try reinstalling Xcode or the simulator runtime.

Could you please let me know how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't (At least in an Official way).

[image]

Taken from [Xcode Beta 2 Documentation](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7_beta_2/Xcode_7_beta_2_Release_Notes.pdf) (Page 7).

Hope it helps.

EDIT SEPT - 2015:

Thanks Cœur for the info, now you can use previous versions of ios simulator.

Comment: Further to this: I've tried to find any sort of official or semi-official statement on whether this is likely to be the case after beta. I've failed.

Comment: Link is dead. iOS 8.1 to 8.4 Simulators are supported. Spelling mistake at 'Docummentation'.

Comment: Not sure if this would still be relevant but iOS 7 simulator was working fine on the XCode 7.0 (final). After upgrade to 7.1 I get the same exact error msg as OP.

Answer (score 35):

Took a lot of browsing but I finally found a solution that worked for me (tried Gend's answer but didn't work). Execute the following lines:

```
sudo mv "/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 7.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/host/liblaunch_sim.dylib"{,.bak}

sudo ln -sf "/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/system/host/liblaunch_sim.dylib" "/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 7.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/host/liblaunch_sim.dylib"
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/leecade/83b4e710d7c741152527

Comment: Works in XCode 7 beta 5 for 7.1 simulator. Thanks

Comment: In XCode 7 beta 6 I don't see this error, but I can't launch app because it stuck in loading state.

Comment: One of my computers has no "/Library/Developer/", the other has an empty "/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/" folder.

Comment: I don't have a CoreSimulator folder in /Library/Developer.

Comment: I got this to work under Xcode 7.0 release too, just had to change "Xcode-beta.app" into "Xcode.app".

Comment: The IPC protocol used by the iOS 7.1 and iOS 8+ liblaunch_sim.dylib are not the same.  You will run into issues doing this.

Comment: @mike have u managed to launch an app on ios7 sim in xcode 7?

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia do you have an alternative suggestion to this? Where do we find the iOS 8+ liblaunch_sim.dylib?

Comment: @deej yes, it worked in Xcode 7 beta 1, afterwards iOS7 simulator disappeared. So for now there is no way to test it but on a device.

Comment: Couldn't run 7.1 simulator on XCode 7.1 official with same error. I updated the commands to `sudo mv "/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 7.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/host/liblaunch_sim.dylib"{,.bak}`   ...then  `sudo ln -sf "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/system/host/liblaunch_sim.dylib" "/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 7.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/host/liblaunch_sim.dylib"`. Runs, but no output log

Comment: 7.1 simulator appears in xcode 7.1.1 and xcode is able to install apps, but they have to be run manually. debugging not working either

Comment: unable to boot simulator

Comment: @Prcela try to close all and the run it or even a restart, I had problems at first as well, so I tried many combination and finally it worked.

Comment: For Xcode 7.2.1 it ends up with "unable to boot simulator" alert. As before, I can't run iOS 7 simulator, but now alert message is different.

Answer (score 6):

First, find the target file:

```
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/system/host/liblaunch_sim.dylib
```

You need make backup liblaunch_sim.dylib (Just in case). 
Second, copied to destination (**Remember to backup**)

```
/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 7.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/host/liblaunch_sim.dylib
```

And If need it to:
iOS 8.1.simruntime
iOS 8.2.simruntime
iOS 8.3.simruntime
All done.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I can't find the CoreSimulator folder under /Library/Developer. Why is that?

Comment: @kevinl I find CorseSimulator but Profiles doesn't appear, just "Devices". Tell me if you find it ! And I will tell you if I find :)

Comment: @Viny76 I ended up placing the liblaunc_sim.dylib after getting the iOS 7.1 simulator SDK from my old xcode located: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/usr/lib/system/host/liblaunch_sim.dylib
now it works

Comment: Now I get "Unable to boot the Simulator."

Answer (score 2):

When you are using sudo command and terminal says: "Command not found"
Then use command like below.

## sudo su (enter)

$ sudo mv "/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 8.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/host/liblaunch_sim.dylib"{,.bak}(enter)

$ sudo mv "/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 7.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/host/liblaunch_sim.dylib"{,.bak}(enter)

$ sudo ln -sf "/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/system/host/liblaunch_sim.dylib" "/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 8.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/host/liblaunch_sim.dylib"(enter)

$ sudo ln -sf "/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/system/host/liblaunch_sim.dylib" "/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 7.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/host/liblaunch_sim.dylib"(enter)
Exit(enter)

Now relaunch Xcode 7 if open earlier.you will be able to run simulators.

Comment: when I try the above, for 7.1, I get

mv: rename /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 7.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/host/liblaunch_sim.dylib to /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 7.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/host/liblaunch_sim.dylib.bak: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 7 beta 6 this seems to be possible now.

http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7_beta_6/Xcode_7_beta_6_Release_Notes.pdf

> Xcode 7.0 beta now supports downloadable legacy simulators. (20699475)

I haven't found a place to download these yet though. I will update when/if I find them.

Comment: Any update?  I'd love to know where to download these!

Comment: The only thing I've found so far is Gend's answer above and pulling them out of the previous Xcode. Per this thread https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17108 it looks like there isn't going to be an official way to do this.