# Can I debug my app on iOS 7 from Xcode 7?

Tags: ios, debugging, ios7.1, xcode7-beta6

Can I debug my app on iOS 7 from Xcode 7?

From what I can tell Xcode 7 just ignores any plugged in devices with iOS 7 installed. Is this just a fluke or is this a permanent change to Xcode?

(Using: Xcode 7 beta 6, iPhone 4S iOS 7.1)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The **BAD** news is that you can't test your app on iOS 7 simulators. At least not with Xcode 7.3.1. If you are using previous Xcode beta then you should check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31851008/396949).

The **GOOD** news is that you can test it on real device running iOS 7. I tested mine with Xcode 7.3.1 on iPhone 4 running iOS 7.1.2.

**UPDATE**: 
The only way I have found so far to test your app on iOS 7 simulators is by installing OS X 10.10 Yosemite and using Xcode 6 (tested with OS X 10.10.5 and Xcode 6.4) side by side with Xcode 7.

**UPDATE**: Xcode version updated to 7.3.1.

Comment: Yup, just had to wait for the debugging symbols to download!

Answer (score 0):

The Xcode 7 beta does not support iOS 7.

It's not necessarily a permanent change, but the general way that the beta works.

Once Xcode 7 is released, the earlier runtimes may be supported, and you will be able to test on devices that are running older releases.

Comment: "you will be able to test on devices that are running older releases." Do you have a source for this?