# How to debug iOS 7.1 simulator on Xcode 7?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I updated Xcode 7 and write some new code.
The problem is that my app support iOS 7.1, that require run from Xcode 6.4 to run iOS 7.1 simulator. But I can not run the app from Xcode 6.4 any more, because there's some new coding syntax that is only run from Xcode 7.
How can I debug my app for iOS 7.1.
Thank you!

Comment: You may need to reconsider supporting iOS 7.1 https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/

Comment: Most of the closely-related questions here indicate that you simply can't: [How can I run the iOS 7.1 simulator in Xcode 7.0 b2?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31056634) [Can I debug my app on iOS 7 from Xcode 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32363456) [How to install iOS 7 and onwards simulators in Xcode 7 beta 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32137582)

Answer (score 5):

1. Build your app in Xcode 7.
2. Quit Xcode 7.
3. Open up Xcode 6.4.
4. Launch the Simulator.app from Xcode 6.4
5. Run 'sudo xcode-select -s /path/to/Xcode-6.4.app'
6. Run 'xcrun simctl install booted /path/to/the/built/simulator.app'
7. Your app should be visible in the iOS 7.1 sim.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but the question was "how to debug" )) I see that I can run the app in iOS 7.1 simulator from xcode 6.4, but can I attach xcode 7 debugger to the simulator then?

Comment: Yeah, just attach to the running process using the debugger just like you'd attach to any running process.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Xcode 7 doesn't have any code syntax. That's the iOS version. And</strike> If you are using any new API, your app will crash on lower versions.

Before using the newer API calls on existing framework objects, you may want to check `respondsToSelector:` on the object to avoid crashes. And you need to have a fallback method for lower API versions.

But if you are using iOS 9 only frameworks, Contacts framework for instance, you need to check the device's iOS version before using the framework to avoid crashes.

Comment: I checked all these new api while coding with Xcode 7.0.
I mean, now I need to debug with iOS 7.1. If that, I need to build with Xcode 6.4. The problem is the app can not be built with Xcode 6.4

Comment: Sadly you need to find a device running iOS 7. You can't compile new code with Xcode 6.

Comment: "Xcode 7 doesn't have any code syntax. That's the iOS version" iOS itself _definitely_ doesn't have any "code syntax" -- in fact, it makes more sense to say that Xcode does, because it's the _compiler_ that allows usage of stuff like lightweight generics that OP's probably referring to (albeit sometimes with framework support, as with [collection literals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425976/compiler-error-expected-method-not-found-when-using-subscript-on-nsarray)).