# Unable to open liblaunch_sim.dylib

Tags: ios, ios9, xcode7

Today I have updated xcode. when i tried to run project on simulator(ios version < 9.0) I got this error.

**"Unable to open liblaunch_sim.dylib. Try reinstalling Xcode or the simulator runtime.**

It ran perfectly on ios9.0 simulator.
here is screen shot. please help me.[image]
[image]

Answer (score 11):

This will also occur when you don't have the simulator actually installed within XCode.  I recently upgraded to XCode 7.1 and didn't install all simulators and received this same error.

- Go to Preferences -> Downloads
- Verify you have a checkmark next to the desired Simulator you are trying to run within XCode.
- If no checkmark, then install the simulator of choice.  8.1, 8.2, 8.3, 8.4

Comment: Ya. but where is option for 7.1 simulator? I m not able to see 7.1

Comment: I don't think there's a 7.1 simulator option in XCode 7.1 and above.  I only see iOS 8.0 simulators and above now.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that there is an "officially supported" way to solve this yet, but have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31851008/768207) (which originates from [this more detailed troubleshoot](https://gist.github.com/leecade/83b4e710d7c741152527)) for a potential fix.

[Edit] In you case, try running those:

```
sudo cp "/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 8.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/host/liblaunch_sim.‌​dylib"{,.bak}

sudo ln -sf "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/D‌​eveloper/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/system/host/liblaunch_sim.dylib" "/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 8.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/host/liblaunch_sim.‌​dylib"
```

Comment: Did the command output any kind of error?  What version of Xcode do you have? What emulator version numbers did you try to the command with?

Comment: Try with 8.1 or 7.1, and be sure to remove the -beta in Xcode-beta.app if you are not using Xcode beta.

Comment: i m not using beta version of xcode! i have updated xcode.

Comment: My point is: don't just copy and paste both commands from the article I linked. Be sure to 1) Change the "Xcode-beta.app" part to "Xcode.app" and 2) Change the iOS version number in both commands to the version of an "older" simulator that you have installed (ex 8.1)

Comment: Updated my answer with commands that include the changes I mentioned. Just check if there are any errors that pop up when you execute one or the other.

Comment: Worked for me on Yosemite with Xcode 7.1 and trying to run iOS 7.1 simulator

Answer (score 1):

First, find the target file:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib/system/host/liblaunch_sim.dylib
You need make backup liblaunch_sim.dylib

Second, copied to destination (Remember to backup)

/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 7.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/host/liblaunch_sim.dylib
And If need it to: iOS 8.1.simruntime iOS 8.2.simruntime iOS 8.3.simruntime All done.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem this problem occurs when we have multiple versions of Xcode Installed ... So i force quit all the xcode and simulator and then open the xcode version you want to open.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this error when I tried to install an iOS 12 simulator runtime on Apple Silicon Mac on macOS Monterey.

Solution was to install Rosetta, which can be done via the Terminal like so:

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```