# WatchKit and iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, watchkit

I have a project that supports devices that have at least iOS 7 installed. 
To test the app on iOS 7 I am using Xcode 6, by using corresponding iPhone simulator.
Recently I have included a WatchKit extension app in my project, which has as minimum target the iOS 8.

Therefore, I am unable to build on Xcode 6, because the scheme that contains the WatchKit is not recognized, as well as unable to test the parent app using Xcode 7, which has no iOS7 simulator.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
Here is the error i get on Xcode 6 when building :

[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24Rm4.png)

But when I try to change the platform i get these options, which do not include WatchOS: 
[Platform options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIZDv.png)

Lastly, xCode 7 does not have an iPhone simulator for iOS 7.

Also, I would like to know if it's possible to test the app on simulator only.

Comment: try Xcode 7.1 , and have one device with iOS 7 version

Comment: The problem is that I do not have a device with iOS 7 and I'd like to use a simulator if possible.

Comment: you can download the iOS 7 simulator by clicking on add additional simulator from the Xcode itself, check my answer dude :)

Comment: did you find the solution , If not let me know, will try to help you

Comment: you can download the iOS 7.1 simulator in Xcode 7 itslef

Comment: Please upvote my answer, and mark it as correct if you found it really worth, if not let me know dude :)

Comment: When I try to build on xCode 7 and iPhone simulator iOS7 I get this error:  "Unable to open liblaunch_sim.dylib.  Try reinstalling Xcode or the simulator runtime."

But I cannot install the iOS 7 runtime form Xcode 7 (the option isn't there). I downloaded it from Xcode 6 and I guess it was passed onto Xcode 7. I have also found some posts saying that it's not possible to run iOS 7 simulator on Xcode 7.

Maaaan, this is a headache... Is your Xcode 7 able to download iOS 7 runtime as you mentioned? It might be that my version is bugged then.

Comment: check out this link dude "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821827/unable-to-open-liblaunch-sim-dylib"

Comment: have you solved this issue??

Comment: nope, not yet... I tried everything from the link you gave me but nothing worked for the iOS 7 simulator

Answer (score 0):

Please download Xcode 7.1 and use a iPhone 4 device, maximum support for iPhone 4 is iOS 7, so better try your testing with real device instead of simulator,

If you want to use simulator better download it with the help of Xcode like below

[image: get the simulator from xcode] 
[image: After downloaded the iOS 7.1 simulator]

Comment: What you shown is adding/removing devices, not downloading. And there are no 7.x simulators in Xcode 7 downloads. And iOS 7.1 simulator will not work on Xcode 7 on Yosemite.