# How can i run ios7.1 simulator in xcode 7? Is there a possible way?

Tags: xcode, ios7.1

When I run ios7.1 simulator Xcode shows error message:

[image: Error message inside XCode]

How to fix this?

Comment: I have similar issue. Some simulators was inside the list but can not run. I suppose they was disabled when installing new version of XCode.

Comment: I see this:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32137582/how-to-install-ios-7-and-onwards-simulators-in-xcode-7-beta-5].Then i give up to try.

Answer (score 0):

You can install other versions of simulators, and the problem will be solved. This problem is explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33554062/5806210