# iOS 7.1 simulator not working on Xcode 7.1

Tags: xcode, ios7, ios-simulator

Since updating to Xcode 7.1, I have seen the iOS 7.1 Simulators return as a build option. However, when building to these, I get the following error:

> **The iOS 7.1 simulator runtime is not available.**
>
> Unable to open
>   liblaunch_sim.dylib.  Try reinstalling Xcode or the simulator runtime.

Now I know in Xcode 7.0 the iOS 7.1 Simulators were not available, but they also were not visible, so I'm wondering why they have re-appeared?

Can anyone explain what's going on?

Comment: This was also happening in the beta, it looks like a bug: [bugreport](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Still you  running in Beta version?

Comment: Download latest simulator , it mean iOS 9 or 8  simulator  !!!

Comment: No. It's the official release Version 7.1 (7B91b). Of course I downloaded the iOS 9 and 8 simulators, but I have to test the application on iOS 7 as well.

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/53640/ios-7-1-simulator-missing-in-xcode-7-do-not-upgrade-to-ios-9-if-you-need-it

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check [How can I run the iOS 7.1 Simulator in Xcode 7.0 beta 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31056634/how-can-i-run-the-ios-7-1-simulator-in-xcode-7-0-beta-2)
2. Also, you may use simulator iphone 4s (9.1) and just compile your code for 7.1

Comment: 1. I checked it already, and it was not working.
2. What I actually need, is the other way around.
Let's just hope that it will be fixed in the next release.